# field goes out of scope java

Tags: java, multithreading, arraylist

I have some problem with multithreaded application. I want to load the data from a CSV like file and store it in a buffer for later retrieval.

Seems like the animals list goes out of scope when the thread is finished(?), there is something about java threading I don't understand and will be grateful for assistance.

The way it's invoked:

```
ParseCSV parser = new ParseCSV(null);
EventQueue.invokeLater(parser);
System.err.println("printing!");
```

EDIT - as requested, this is the part that fails - the content of praser buffer is empty at this point. I thought that if I use new keyword in the parser, the content of animals will be persistent.

```
while(parser.hasNext()){
    System.err.println("#");
    System.err.println(parser.getNext().toString());
}
```

The parser class:

```
public class ParseCSV implements Runnable{

    private String path = null;
    private File file = null;
    private static Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(ParseCSV.class.getName());
    private volatile ArrayList<Animal> animals = new ArrayList<Animal>();
    private int pointer =0;



    public ParseCSV(String path) {
        animals = new ArrayList<Animal>(); //tried to reinitialize, didn't help this is where the problem occurs
        if(path == null){
            JFileChooser jfc = new JFileChooser();
            jfc.showOpenDialog(null);
            file = jfc.getSelectedFile();
            this.path = file.getAbsolutePath();
        }
        else {
            this.path = path;

        }
        log.debug("Initialized file parser for " + this.path);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        log.debug("begining file parse");
        System.err.println("runnner");
        try {
            Scanner fileScan = new Scanner(this.file);
            while(fileScan.hasNextLine()){
                parseLine(fileScan.nextLine());
            }
            fileScan.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            log.error("Exception occured: " + e.getMessage() + "\nstack:\n" + e.getStackTrace());
            System.err.println("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void parseLine(String nextLine) {
        Scanner lineScanner = new Scanner(nextLine);
        lineScanner.useDelimiter("\\s\\|\\s");
        if(lineScanner.hasNext()){
            Animal an =             new Animal(lineScanner.next(), //person
                    lineScanner.next(), //animal
                    Integer.parseInt(lineScanner.next()), //emp-number
                    lineScanner.next(), //date
                    Integer.parseInt(lineScanner.next()), //ani-number
                    lineScanner.next());
            animals.add(an);    //contract ID
            System.err.println(an.toString()); //prints correct result!
        }
        lineScanner.close();
    }

    public String getPath() {       return path;    }
    public void setPath(String path) {      this.path = path;   }

    public boolean hasNext(){
        System.err.println("size of data = " + animals.size());
        if(animals.size() == pointer || animals.isEmpty()) return false;
        else return true;
    }
    public Sale getNext(){
        if(animals.size() == pointer) return null;
        return animals.get(pointer++);

    }

}
```

EDIT - added comments to point out where the problem appears

Comment: The only variables which go out of scope are the ones declared inside the `run()` method.

Comment: does the content of animals go out of scope then? The animals are filling up during the run() as I can see in the debugger, but after the run() method finishes, the animals list is empty again

Comment: 'I thought that if I use new keyword in the parser, the content of animals will be persistent.' Why?

Comment: because I thought that the new will create a new object and when the object is placed in the storage array that has a wider scope, those object will not be removed by the garbage collector(they still have valid references there) - and I was correct it appears as the problem is elsewhere - see answer from Amit Mahajan

Answer (score 2):

You need to wait for the Parser thread to finish (currently both are happening at same time) This may be the reason that your program is not printing anything.
you can try adding some logging statements and check if the sequence is proper on not.

Comment: Seems like this is the case! I changed the `invokeLater` to `invokeAndWait`. Could you please advice on what is the correct way to solve this? invoke and wait will block and for large file it might be a problem, so there must be a smarter way, something like "do other things until the data gets available", a flag perhaps with some condition?

Comment: I am not expert in new concurrent api for swing, you may try invokeLater along with custom lock Conditions. i.e. Condition objects inside Lock can be used like wait and notify ( They tells when one thread can read if data is available)

Answer (score 1):

`EventQueue#invokeLater` adds a task to the event queue, so it might not be done when coming to the next line.
Use `EventQueue#invokeAndWait` instead, it waits for the task to finish.

Comment: Did that, as I wrote in the comment for Amits solution - can I make it so that I don't block the entire program while waiting for the data to load? When I use a test file with 3 entries it's no big deal, but if I try to throw in an entire zoo...

Comment: @user3002166 [SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html)s are a comfortable solution to run background tasks with progress updates in the swing GUI. Be sure to take a look at it^^

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems with your code. Some of them actually leads to the problem, and some just shows that you don't really understand what you are trying to do.

```
private volatile ArrayList<Animal> animals = new ArrayList<Animal>();
```

Why are you using volatile on this? Each thread have their own animals list, so they are just used by one thread. If your main class had a animals model that everyone added to, you would have needed to make it volatile, since multiple threads could access it.

```
    animals = new ArrayList<Animal>(); //tried to reinitialize, didn't help this is where the problem occurs
```

This isn't going to change anything. It might be useful if you think the method could get called multiple times and you want a fresh list each time, but it's probably just a waste.

Now onto the real problem:

When you call a thread it's because you want it to run in the background and not stop the main program execution. Then you can get back to the result at some time when it's actually finished. As people have said, if you just want a new thread without it really running in the background you could do EventQueue#invokeAndWait, but for your case this isn't the solution.

You could use the observer pattern. To do this you make an interface that has a notify method (call it parseListner or something). The parser has a list of parseListerners. When the parser finish parsing it tells all the listeners (by calling a method on the interface). So you end up with code sort of like this:

```
public interface ParseListner{
   void fileParsed(String fileName, List<Animal> animals);
}

public class Main implements ParseListner{
   public void main(){
      ParseCSV parser = new ParseCSV(this);
      EventQueue.invokeLater(filePath, parser);
   }
   public void fileParsed(String fileName, List<Animal> animals){
      System.Out.Println(doneParsing);
   }
}
```

public class ParseCSV implements Runnable{
    List listners = new ArrayList<>();
    public ParseCSV(String path, ParseListner caller) {
    listner.add(caller)
    }

```
@Override
public void run() {
    //all the parsestuff
    for(ParseListner p : listners)
       p.parsedFile(fileName, animals);
}
```

I used a list because it's almost always useful (so you can do multiple things when it's done).

Comment: _If your [threads shared an] animals model..., you would have needed to make it volatile_.   Making it `volatile` would not have been enough in that case.  The application would need to use _mutual exclusion_ (i.e., `synchronized` blocks) to prevent the ArrayList from becoming corrupted.